# 4.1: XML Layout LinkedHashMap error

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_firstname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have this XML Layout above, everything is working fine in 4.0.3, but when I apply it to 4.1, it produces this error below. When I removed EditText layout is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue right now It  doesn’t come from ADT 20 but from the rendering library of Jelly Bean. So We need to wait for an update of JB to have a fix.

But as a workaround, we are able to solve this by disabling the *SpellChecker*.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.LinkedHashMap.eldest()Ljava/util/Map$Entry;
    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:206)
    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:306)
    at android.widget.SpellChecker.resetSession(SpellChecker.java:141)
    at android.widget.SpellChecker.setLocale(SpellChecker.java:147)
```

So add  `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to your EditText and you will get this problem resolved.

For more details see this [link](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/small-issue-with-adt-20-and-sdk-16-and-how-to-fix-it).

Answer (score 1):

Dont know the reason but placing `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` in EditText is working.